# PrimeNG: how to 'pack' or 'build' the project after making changes?

Tags: angular, primeng, ng2-bootstrap

I use primeng in my angular application. I wanted to add some functionality to one of the components so I followed the instructions  (https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/wiki/Building-From-Source) and got all of my changes to work. Now I want to package it up so I can install this modified branch in my application. How do I go about doing that?

I've done this before with ng2-bootstrap by running 'npm pack' and then installing the generated tar package in my application. I tried doing the same with primeng but my project errored because the primeng.js file wasn't there. I'm assuming I need to do it a different way but I don't know how and I don't have much webpack/gulp experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Fork to your GitHub account
2. Clone package
3. Make a new branch
4. Make changes to new branch

Then run the following commands in order;

**`npm install`** - Downloads the dependencies

**`gulp build`** - Creates resource bundle for css

**`npm run build-prod`** - Which runs the build scripts.

You can then push this package to your own GitHub account and with a different branch name and run the following in your project you require the custom build:

```
npm install git://github.com/<user>/<project>.git#<branch>
```

Then whenever priming makes changes on the master you can merge them with your custom branch.

Comment: I did all of these steps successfully but I am still getting the same error: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:3000/node_modules/primeng/primeng.js". The only step I didn't do is fork to my github account but these steps should work locally too yeah?

Comment: So how did you do the npm install? What is your project using for the build system? Are you using any of the following angular-cli, WebPack, SystemJS?

Comment: Im using systemjs, similar to how angular quickstart loads

Comment: Your systemjs config does that have the correct path for the import? Are you simply just copying the primeng folder to your project node_modules or are you doing npm install?

Comment: I tried npm install on the modified primeng branch folder as a whole. So in my project, I tried "npm install primeng-branch" and then the primeng branch was installed to my node_modules directory. I also tried doing npm pack inside of the primeng branch and then installing the generated tarball  in my project but that resulted in the same error as well. I am not copying the primeng branch directory into my node_modules directory

Comment: The primeng.js file is not there if that helps. So after installing the modified branch, there is no primeng.js file. It looks like I copied the directory into node_modules, but I didn't

Comment: Your modified branch is that possible to put on GitHub? Then I can directly test that to see if I can spot the problem.

Comment: Yeah, here it is https://github.com/quiringk/PrimeNGModifiedBranch. I don't think anything changed and if it did, it'd be a very small change. So it should pretty close to master when I cloned it.

Comment: That isn't to do with the .gitignore is it? Since that file is in there. Just cloned it to my system now.

Comment: Looking into the package a little more I see that npm build-prod runs webpack and creates a webpack bundle. That's not really what you're after. So really what you need to do is run `gulp build & tsc` the .js will be in the root folder and the other assets will be in resources.

Comment: I tried running that command and got the same results I've been getting when I install the primeNg directory in my project. Do I need to use webpack instead of systemjs to be able to accomplish making these changes?

Comment: `npm run build` does not work in this example because the angular dependencies are not met.  However I don't want them in a tgz prod build.  How do I build a .tgz like the one `npm install primeng` would provide?  (without the showcase and angular requirements)  All my attempts have gotten closer but eventually end in sadness.  Removing the showcase and hence angular requirement is just the first step it appears.

Answer (score 2):

In the forked PrimeNG v5, package.json need to be updated with following lines to build and redistribute.

additions to package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "build-components": "ngc -p tsconfig-release.json",
    "build-assets": "gulp build-assets",
    "build-styles": "node-sass src/assets/components -o src/assets/components",
    "build-redistribute": "npm run build-components && npm run build-assets && npm run build-styles"
  }
  "devDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
  }
```

install node-sass and run the following command to build

```
npm run build-redistribute
```

Ref : https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?p=159783#p159783

Comment: Doesn't work for PrimeNG 7 anymore, at least not for me.

Answer (score 1):

## primeNG > 7

Optionally add a `dist` script in package.json to build the distribution files

```
{
  "name": "primeng",
  "version": "7.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "dist": "ngc -p tsconfig-release.json && gulp build-assets && gulp build-exports"
  },
```

and then just do a

```
npm run dist
```

**note that with version 7.0.0 it threw me random errors when running this command**

> [08:38:19] Starting 'themes'...
>   events.js:174
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>         ^
>   Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'primeng/resources/components/accordion/accordion.css'

another

> [08:35:44] 'images' errored after 134 ms
>   [08:35:44] Error: EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir 'primeng/resources/images'

**I suppose it was due to a racing condition or something. If it happens just try the command again until it builds correctly.**

you may also run the commands without adding the script

```
npm install
./node_modules/.bin/ngc -p tsconfig-release.json
./node_modules/.bin/gulp build-assets
./node_modules/.bin/gulp build-exports
```

then you can generate a tar.gz file which you may use in your project

```
npm pack
```

and install in your project with

```
npm install ~/primeng/primeng-7.0.0.tar.gz
```

npm install [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) state that you may use also a folder, so, you also may install as

```
npm install ~/primeng/
```

I tried it, but it threw the following exception in my project so I had to use the tar.gz

> StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[RouterOutlet -> ChildrenOutletContexts]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for ChildrenOutletContexts!

You may also publish your own version on npm

```
npm login
npm publish
```

and use it instead of the primeng official distribution

```
npm install @youruser/primeng
```

credits to @Anulal for pointing us in the right direction

Comment: Running all commands chained solves the race condition


`./node_modules/.bin/ngc -p tsconfig-release.json && ./node_modules/.bin/gulp build-assets && ./node_modules/.bin/gulp build-exports && npm pack
`

Answer (score 0):

**primeng >= 9**
The build process has changed to use `ng-packagr` in primeng 9.  This method was confirmed in primeng 10.

To build run once to install ng-packager:

```
npm install ng-packager --save-dev
```

Run to build each time

```
npm run build-lib
```

I haven't built version 9 using `ng-packagr`.  Should be the same according to this [link](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/8057).